# Pause all other threads while one thread is working in C# and resume after the work is done by that thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.8

I am working on a code in which I need to trigger a function when a desired condition meets. That function can be triggered from different different threads parallelly via different event handlers. Problem starts when I need to call same function from two or more threads at the same time due to multiple event handlers triggering at the same time. I am making some changes in the value in that function and then returning back to a different class and this is not working properly since one of the event handler triggering that function is over-riding the other value in case the function is being triggered at the same time. Is there a way to pause all the other threads triggering that same function until the thread working on that particular function completes processing. I am using Windows form application with .net framework 4.8.

I have tried using thread.Sleep method but that's not what I needed. Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you thought about using [a simple `lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)?

Comment: Code would be awesome here.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock). This will ensure some section(s) of code can only be run by a single thread at a time, usually called a *critical section*. Any other thread trying to take the same lock will be paused, or *blocked* until the first thread releases the lock.

If locks are new to you I would highly recommend avoiding any type of multi threaded development until you have spent a bit more time studying thread safety. Multi threading is difficult, and many errors can be difficult to reproduce. This is not an area where trial and error is appropriate.

Comment: Online material for studying multithreading: [Threading in C#](https://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: If possible can anyone share some study material related to event handlers, delegates and lambda expressions in c# as well. Its really difficult to find some good material online. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @DharuvVerma21 Seeking of site resources is explicitly [of topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But the [programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/) is in general a good place to start.

Comment: @DharuvVerma21, see also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) Always keep in mind though, that although people often say that locks prevent multiple threads from using the same function or entering the same "critical section" at the same time, the _real_ purpose of locking is to prevent multiple threads from accessing the same _data_ at the same time. If the data can be accessed from within more than one function/section, then _all_ of the sections/functions must be protected by the same lock.